# Amazon Seller Fetch with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been trying to write something in VBA to get all seller names & prices from any amazon page, here's an product listing example:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00KTOE41I/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all

I've tried every option in VBA to return the innertext/innerhtml of certain tags which contain the data I want but it fails no matter what method I use.

getElementsByClassName - Error,
getElementsByName - Error,
getElementById - Error
getElementsByTagName - Brings back something like "[object HTMLSpanElement]"

seller id's are contained within this tag:
p class="a-spacing-small olpSellerName"
& prices which are contained within this tag:

Here's my code, I know it needs a for loop in there to cycle through all instances of the specified tag, but I can't even get it to return the innertext. I've tried diming the variables as "IHTMLElement" or "IHTMLElementCollection" But nothing works.

Also, I have Microsoft HTML Object Library & Internet Controls Checked.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunNewModule()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00KTOE41I/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all"

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document
Set ie = Nothing
Dim table
Dim sellers

UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
Set table = html.getElementsByTagName("a").Item

sellers = table.all
UserForm1.TextBox7.Text = sellers

Cells.Clear
Range("A3").Value = "Seller"
Range("B3").Value = "Price"
Range("A4").Value = sellers

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't find any such tag here: view-source:http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00KTOE41I/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Comment: You're right I updated that ie.navigate url. the tags should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this URL: *http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00KTOE41I/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all*

You can grab the price like this:  `Set priceData = html.getElementsByClassName("olpOfferPrice")`

Then output it to column B like this:

```
cntr = 4
For Each Item In priceData
    Range("B" & cntr) = Item.innerText
    cntr = cntr + 1
Next Item
```

---

Same thing for seller: `Set sellerData = html.getElementsByClassName("olpSellerName")`

Except this will only return sellers with names in text not images.

---

Results:

[image]

---

Make sure you close IE (`ie.Quit`) otherwise you keep it in memory.